# java script to typescript conversion for an angular based app

Tags: html, typescript

https://github.com/karthik2296/abc.git

The above code is the calorie counter code and it is giving the following errors below attached in the image file

No error but the code doesnt run when the bmi.component.ts file is present in the form 
I am new to the platform and did quite a amount of research and not able to figure it out.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bmi',
  templateUrl: './bmi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bmi.component.css']
})
export class BmiComponent implements OnInit {

  static module(arg0: any, arg1: any): any {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


}


'use strict';

var app = BmiComponent.module('app',  []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope  :any ){
  //dropdown container
  $scope.activities = [
    {name: 'Little to no exercise', multiply: 1.2},
    {name: 'Light exercise (1–3 days per week)', multiply: 1.375}, 
    {name: 'Moderate exercise (3–5 days per week)', multiply: 1.55},
    {name: 'Heavy exercise (6–7 days per week)', multiply: 1.725},
    {name: 'Very heavy exercise (twice per day, extra heavy workouts)', multiply: 1.9}
  ];
  //dropdown container
  $scope.goals = [
    {name: 'Lose weight - 1lb per week', alt: 'tone', cals: 500}, 
    {name: 'Lose weight - 2lb per week', alt: 'tone', cals: 1000},
    {name: 'Gain weight - 1lb per week', alt: 'bulk', cals: -500},
    {name: 'Gain weight - 2lb per week', alt: 'bulk',cals: -1000},
    {name: 'Maintain weight', alt: 'tone', cals: 0}
  ];
  //function to get total BMR
  $scope.bmr = function() {
    let standard = (parseInt($scope.weight, 10) * 10) +
          (parseInt($scope.height) * 6.25) - 
          (parseInt($scope.age) * 5); //both genders only differ on the last addition or subtraction

      if($scope.gender === 'male'){
        return  standard + 5
      } else if ($scope.gender === 'female'){
        return standard - 161
      } else {
        return //break out and angular number validation will take care of NaN 
      }
    };
  //function to get total dailys cals
  $scope.cals = function() {
    if(Number($scope.bmr) !== NaN && $scope.selectedActivity != null && $scope.selectedGoal != null){
    return $scope.bmr() * Number($scope.selectedActivity.multiply) - Number($scope.selectedGoal.cals)
    } else {
      return
      };
  };
  //of daily cals how much should be protein
  $scope.proteinCals = function(){
   return  $scope.cals() * .55
  };
  //as above for carbs
  $scope.carbsCals = function(){
    return $scope.cals() * .25
  };
  //as above for fat
  $scope.fatCals = function(){ 
    return $scope.cals() * .2
  };

  //for each meal type, what % of the above should each contain
  $scope.breakfast = [
    {name: 'protein', value: function(){return $scope.proteinCals() * 0.0252 / 4}}, 
    {name: 'carbs', value: function(){return $scope.carbsCals() * .0933 / 4}},
    {name: 'fat', value: function(){return $scope.fatCals() * 0.3467 / 8}}
  ]; 
  $scope.snack = [
    {name: 'protein', value: function(){return $scope.proteinCals() * 0.0573 / 4}}, 
    {name: 'carbs', value: function(){return $scope.carbsCals() * .1295 / 4}},
    {name: 'fat', value: function(){return $scope.fatCals() * 0.04 / 8}}
  ]; 
  $scope.mainMeal = [
    {name: 'protein', value: function(){return $scope.proteinCals() * 0.4014 / 4}}, 
    {name: 'carbs', value: function(){return $scope.carbsCals() * .2591 / 4}},
    {name: 'fat', value: function(){return $scope.fatCals() * 0.2666 / 8}}
  ]; 
  //end of meal section

});
```

Comment: See [ask]. [Edit] the question and provide a [mcve] and tell us what you want to do, what you have tried and what result you get. Error message especially should be provided as text in the body of the question.

Comment: @jdv can you help me out?

Comment: The best way to attract good answers is to make sure your question tells us what you are doing and the exact problem including error messages. What is the error message? Tell us what you have tried already. Basically, you are asking us to debug your code, and that will not get you much traction here. How have you debugged this yourself so far?  Tell us in the text of the question as much of this as you can.